# unrecognized selector sent to instance | Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

The app crash on startup and I have this error in the console :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Chartboost showInterstitial]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f844c9b74e0'

my code is :

```
#import "cocos2d.h"

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "IntroLayer.h"
#import "AppSpecificValues.h"
#import <RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h>

#import <Chartboost/Chartboost.h>


@implementation AppController
@synthesize gameCenterManager=gameCenterManager_, currentLeaderBoard=currentLeaderBoard_;
@synthesize window=window_, navController=navController_, director=director_;
@synthesize cb;
@synthesize nScore;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Create the main window
    window_ = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Create an CCGLView with a RGB565 color buffer, and a depth buffer of 0-bits
    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   //kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0    //GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];

    director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    director_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    // Display FSP and SPF
//  [director_ setDisplayStats:YES];

    // set FPS at 60
    [director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

    // attach the openglView to the director
    [director_ setView:glView];

    // for rotation and other messages
    [director_ setDelegate:self];

    // 2D projection
    [director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
//  [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection3D];

    // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
    if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

    // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
    // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
    // You can change anytime.
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

    // If the 1st suffix is not found and if fallback is enabled then fallback suffixes are going to searched. If none is found, it will try with the name without suffix.
    // On iPad HD  : "-ipadhd", "-ipad",  "-hd"
    // On iPad     : "-ipad", "-hd"
    // On iPhone HD: "-hd"
    CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
    [sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];             // Default: NO. No fallback suffixes are going to be used

    [sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];      // Default on iPhone RetinaDisplay is "-hd"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];                   // Default on iPad is "ipad"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipad-hd"];   // Default on iPad RetinaDisplay is "-ipadhd"
    // Assume that PVR images have premultiplied alpha
    [CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];

    self.nScore = 0;

    //Revmobs
    [RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"RevMobAPI"]];

    // and add the scene to the stack. The director will run it when it automatically when the view is displayed.
    [director_ pushScene: [IntroLayer scene]]; 

    [self initGameCenter];

    // Create a Navigation Controller with the Director
    navController_ = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:director_];
    navController_.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    // set the Navigation Controller as the root view controller
//  [window_ addSubview:navController_.view];   // Generates flicker.
    [window_ setRootViewController:navController_];

    // make main window visible
    [window_ makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

-(void) lunchRevmobADLink
{
    [[RevMobAds session] openAdLinkWithDelegate:self];
}

- (void) setUpRevMob {
    [[RevMobAds session] showFullscreen];
}

-(void) launchChartboost
{
         // Initialize the Chartboost library
        [Chartboost startWithAppId:@"53be6ed01873dc9741aafa"
                      appSignature:@"fcd1715a73c97b22c5ad557323a59d7348476"
                          delegate:self];

    // Begin a user session. This should be done once per boot
    [cb startSession];

    [cb cacheInterstitial];

    [cb cacheMoreApps];
}

-(void) showChartboostInterestitial
{
    // Show an interstitial
    [[Chartboost sharedChartboost] showInterstitial];
}

-(void) showChartboostMoreApps
{
    [[Chartboost sharedChartboost] showMoreApps];
}

// Supported orientations: Landscape. Customize it for your own needs
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}


// getting a call, pause the game
-(void) applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if( [navController_ visibleViewController] == director_ )
        [director_ pause];
}

// call got rejected
-(void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if( [navController_ visibleViewController] == director_ )
        [director_ resume];

    [self launchChartboost];

#ifdef FREE_VERSION
    [self showChartboostInterestitial];
    [self setUpRevMob];
    [self hideAdBanner:YES];

#endif
}
```

and other code.
I tried lot of things! So I ask you now, How I can resolve this???
Thank's in advance!

Comment: Usually helps to turn on all warnings and to use the static analyzer. Shows you bugs before you run the code. Also set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions and check who is calling this.

Comment: When you debug it in Xcode and it crashes, in the console, type `po <address ofinstance>` to identify a bit more which object is sent the message. It is 'print object' message that will return the [object description]. You will see if the `showInterstitial` message is really sent to the right object (surely not, so the cause of the crash).

Comment: but i need to write really this "po <address ofinstance>" or i need to replace the text "address of instance" ?? sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Chartboost documentation](https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/201220095-iOS-Integration) you are not trying to show interstitial the right way :

> 4. To show a static or interstitial video ad:

```
// Show interstitial at location HomeScreen. See Chartboost.h for available location options.
[Chartboost showInterstitial:CBLocationHomeScreen];
```

The way you are doing it has been removed in their SDK 5.x

> All references to [Chartboost sharedChartboost] are now changed to
>   Chartboost:
>
> - [[Chartboost sharedChartboost] showInterstitial:CBLocationHomeScreen]; is now [Chartboost
>     showInterstitial:CBLocationHomeScreen];

Answer (score 0):

you are calling showInterstitial on an instance although it is a class method. it should be something like `[Chartboost showInterstitial...`

Comment: i have the same problem with hideadbanner: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppController hideAdBanner:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f870a412350

Comment: i already try with this : [Chartboost showInterstitial]; but it doesn't work, same problem.

Comment: in the example app it is called like so: `[Chartboost showInterstitial:CBLocationHomeScreen];`. regarding your other problem: you are calling `[self hideAdBanner:YES];` but i do not see a method implementation for that. so it makes sense that you get that error.